# What is shalom bayit

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, shalom-peace, shalom-bayit, halachic-development

I’m curious what the concept of Shalom Bayit means in terms of practical Halacha. Is it a mitzvah, a general halachic rule, an ethical principle, or something else? Where is it derived from historically?

Comment: Are you asking what it is or what level of obligation one is under to achieve it?

Comment: It is a principle, the most classic example is probably the example of the Sotah, where Hashem lets us erase His name in order to promote peace and harmony between husband and wife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gemara uses it to refer to general tranquility in the home
https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.23b.3?lang=bi&with=all
and marital relations https://www.sefaria.org/Steinsaltz_on_Shabbat.152a.7?lang=bi&with=all

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. @Kirk didn't ask for a definition.of "shalom bayis", but what its role is halachically.

Comment: See his last question